# Composer and PSR-4

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

I readed much topics, but no noone resolved my problem.

In main directory i have `composer.json`, `vendor` dir and `core`dir which has `Router.php` file

Router.php

```
namespace Core;

class Router{}
```

composer.sjon

```
 "autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
      "Core\\": "core/"
    },
```

Update of `autoload` generate `0 include classes` and when I try to use Router, there is error `Class 'Core\Router' not found`

I try

`"Core\\": "core"`

`"Core\\Router": "core/"`

`"Core\\Router": "core"`

Nothing work

Answer (score 0):

Use This :

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Core\\": "core/",
    }
},
```

Comment: It's  ``` psr-4 ```

Comment: Yeah, sorry I missed 'r' in comment